# Как вывести в категории товара соотв статью?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

возник вопрос, как можно вывести в категории товара, соответствующей её статью, притом что рубрика по ярлыку совпадает с категорией -- woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

Ну я бы мысли как то так:

1 - Получим "Name" категории

```
 $category = get_the_category(); 
 echo $category[0]->name;
```

2- Получим записи по метке

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category_name' => 'сюда имя из п.1' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Попробуйте такой сценарий.

Comment: Не получается, NULL в get_the_category

Comment: А вы в каком шаблоне это делаете?

Comment: Я это делаю в сниппете через шорткод

Comment: Вам надо Id передать в get_the_category,  я думаю.
Как нибудь так:
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$category = get_the_category($post_id); 

Под рукой Нету ВП развернутого, и не совсем понимаю, как лично у вас все устроено, но попробуйте так)

Comment: Все равно null, но я задампил пост и там тип записи product

Comment: Я написал вот так, <?php
global $post;
if (is_product_category()) {
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->slug;
    }

$args = array( 'category' => $cat);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

Comment: Получаю категорию, передаю её, и все равно все посты выводит